# writing iterrows back into excel rows

Tags: python

I'm trying to take rows from and excel sheet, modify the internal functions, and write them back into their original rows. I've been able to accomplish all of the needed except for re-writing them into their original cells. I've posted the code below, how would I go about accomplishing this?

```
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=4, max_row=9, min_col=2, max_col=2):
    for cell in row:
        print(cell.value)
        roll = chr(ord(cell.value[-3])+1)
        rollList = list(cell.value)
        rollList[8] = roll
        RollListtoString = ''.join(map(str, rollList))
        print(RollListtoString)
```

I've tried turning the "RollListtoString" value into a dictionary and writing like that but was unable to make that work;

```
Dict = {"value": RollListtoString}
        print(Dict)
        row = 4
        for value in Dict:
            wsw.write(row, Dict)
            wsw.write_row(row, 1, Dict)
            row += 1
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Which Excel module are you using?  Each library is entirely different.

Comment: I'm using openpyxl but I'm open to using others if they would be better options

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm also using xlsxwriter

Comment: In your `for value in Dict:` loop, shouldn't you be writing `value` and not `Dict`?

Comment: I'm trying to write the values though, wouldn't changing from "for value in Dict" to "for value in value" not access the Dict? Also, apologies if this was an awful question, I'm relatively new to Python/programming languages in general.

Comment: Are you just trying to change 1 cell in 6 rows, by setting the 8th character to the letter after the third-from-the-end?  Is that the purpose here?  You don't have a reader (`ws`) and a write (`wsw`) open to the same spreadsheet at the same time, do you?

Answer (score 0):

If my summation above is accurate, this should be close to your need.  If there's only one column, you don't need to iterate through the rows.  Just create the new cell and replace it.

```
rownnum = 4
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=4, max_row=9, min_col=2, max_col=2):
    value = row[0].value
    roll = chr(ord(value[-3])+1)
    newcell = value[:8]+roll+value[9:]
    wsw.write(rownum, 2, newcell)
    rownum += 1
```